# Socialization gem - two issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Since the implementation is very trivial, I would like to know your suggestion as how you will use Socialization gem to show "Posts" associated with a followed user. There wasn't a coherent description in the gem guide.

This is what I tried
`Post.where(id: current_user.followers.pluck(:id))`
This throws an error
`wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)`

Also, as suggested in the guide to show the follower/followee count, there is a strange output.
The count in the view starts off with `-2` and counts upwards from there.
Migration
`add_column :users, :followers_count, :integer, :default => 0`
User model by devise

Thanks.

Comment: no idea about that gem, but `Post.where(user_id:` or `current_user.posts...`  makes more sense

Comment: What does that error actually signify - `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)`

Answer (score 2):

As I can see in [socialization](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) you are calling method `followers` 
wrong in with `current_user` check this code which is mentioned inside it
**All followers**

```
celebrity.followers(User)
```

so I can see `current_user.followers.pluck(:id)` is wrong correct it.